# Loop program again after method is executed

Tags: javascript

i guess this is a really simple problem, but i just can't get it to work! I want that my menu should show up again after that i have run a method. Thanks in advance.

```
function menu () {
    var choice = prompt("0. Exit \n\n1. Fahrenheit to Celsius \n2. Celsius to Fahrenheit \n3. Guess a number");
    choice = parseInt(choice);

    if (choice > 4 || choice < 0) {
        alert("FEL!!");
    } else if (isNaN(choice)) {
        alert("Måste vara en siffra");
    }
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
           choice = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            CelsiusToFarenheit();
            break;
        case 2:
            FahrenheitToCelsius();
            break;
        case 3:
            Guess();
            break;
    }
    return choice;
}

do {
    menu();
} while(choice == true);
```

Comment: What does that mean? In what way is it failing? What do you think the cause might or might not be?

Comment: Inside `menu()`, change `var choice = prompt(...` to `choice = prompt(...`, and put the `var choice;` *outside* the function. Then you can get rid of the `return` statement too. Using `var` makes a variable *local* to that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to store the variable returned by the menu() function :

```
function menu () {
    var choice = prompt("0. Exit \n\n1. Fahrenheit to Celsius \n2. Celsius to Fahrenheit \n3. Guess a number");
    choice = parseInt(choice);

    if (choice > 4 || choice < 0) {
        alert("FEL!!");
    } else if (isNaN(choice)) {
        alert("Måste vara en siffra");
    }
    switch (choice) {
        case 0:
           choice = false;
            break;
        case 1:
            CelsiusToFarenheit();
            break;
        case 2:
            FahrenheitToCelsius();
            break;
        case 3:
            Guess();
            break;
    }
    return choice;
}

var choice;
do {
    choice = menu();
} while(choice == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Menu() and after it executes, it is done. Therefore you need to run Menu() again.

Comment: You mean in the method like: 

function CelsiusToFarenheit() {
//Some code
menu();
}

Is that a proper way to do it?